# JAVA Compiling Issue with 2 Classes and External Library

Tags: java, compiler-errors

I am having a compiling issue when trying to compile in the Command Prompt for Windows.
I have the directory setup as follows
I have my .java files in src Directory(Main.java & getSource.java)
I have a .jar file in a SubDirectory of src (./lib/jsoup.jar)

when I try to compile I do

```
C:\src> javac -cp ".;/lib/*" Main.java
```

but I get

```
.\getSource.java:1: error: package org.jsoup does not exist
import org.jsoup.Jsoup;
                ^
.\getSource.java:2: error: package org.jsoup.nodes does not exist
import org.jsoup.nodes.Document;
```

I am not sure where I am going wrong.

I wrote this app through eclipse and it compiles fine in eclipse but when I try to do it through the command line it doesn't work.

Also, I happened to find the eclipse compiled .class and tried to execute that using

```
java Main
```

but it still gives me a related error

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/jsoup/Jsoup
        at getSource.<init>(getSource.java:20)
        at Main.main(Main.java:10)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.jsoup.Jsoup
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        ... 2 more
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

`C:\src> javac -cp .;lib/* Main.java`

Ref : **Understanding class path wildcards** in  http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/tools/windows/classpath.html

To run the program use **java** command like this

`C:\src> java -cp .;lib/* Main`

Comment: Awesome, this compiled it but now when I try to run the program I still get the second error Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/jsoup/Jsoup
        at getSource.<init>(getSource.java:20)
        at Main.main(Main.java:10)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.jsoup.Jsoup
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source